# How can I charge a NiMH cell with a 5 V, 2 A adapter

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, nimh

How can I charge a NiMH cell (1.2 V, 600 mAh) with a 5 V, 2 A adapter? Can I use a resistor in series, and if so, what value?

Comment: Don't do it. It is unsafe. Use a charger built for the purpose.

Comment: Why destroy the battery cell with a 5V input? You need a Ni-MH battery cell CHARGER CIRCUIT, not a simple resistor.

Comment: Like the others suggested you shouldnt charge like this. Many IC's exist that provide all the charging profiles and protections in order to do this safely. You might look into a charging IC like the LTC4060: https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc4060.html#product-overview
It is linear so that might ease your design a little bit.

Comment: The usual. Connect a charger between power supply and battery.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer :**
no, you cannot use a 5V supply to charge a NiMH cell

**Long answer :**
Whatever resistor you put between you NiMh cell and the 5V supply, when the battery is full, there will still be a voltage diferrence, so there will still be current charging the already full battery : so you will distroy it.
Buy yourself a NiMh charger (it costs only a few $).

As an "emergency solution", if you are sure your cell is "empty", then you can charge it with a low current I during a duration T, in such way that you are sure the cell will not be entirely full at the end. (If you keep charging when the cell is full, you destroy it, and on NiMh cells it's not easy to know when they are full).
How to determine I and T?

1. Take the capacity C of your cell, in Ah (if it is expressed in mAh, then divide by 1000 to get it in Ah)
2. Choose yout current. I would recommend somethink around I=C/10 (in A) (or lower).
3. Determine the charging time : theoretically, a complete charging would take T_theoretic=C/I=10 hours (if you use I=C/10). In practice, the cell might not be completly empty, the capacity might be less than annonced (aged cell, mishandled cell, not so honnest seller, wrong temperature, ...). So I would recommend dividing the charging time by 3. So T=T_theoretical/3 (=3h20 if charging at I=C/10)
4. Choose the correct resistor : R=(5V-1.2V)/I. The resistor will dissipate a power P=R*I*I in heat, so make sure the resistor is rated for that amount of power (if it is no power resistor, then it might not). NB : you can choose a lower current at step 2 in order to need a lower power rating for the resistor.

If you respect precisely this procedure, you should be able to recharge about 1/3 cor the capacity of an empty cell : it's not much, but might be enough until you can buy a NiMh charger. I woul recommand you not to push further, or you start risking to overcharge and destroy your cell.

I recommand you NOT TO USE this emergency solution if you have any other possibility

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a resistor in series, and if so, what value?

Yes, you can use a resistor in series. The value must be chosen to limit current to less than the specified 'trickle' charge rate, which is typically capacity / 10. In your case this is 600/10 = 60 mA.

Under charge the cell voltage will quickly rise to ~1.3 V, then gradually rise to ~1.5 V after 12 hours. Applying [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), (5-1.3)/0.06 = 61.7 Ω. The preferred values of 62 Ω or 56 Ω will be close enough. The resistor will dissipate ~(5-1.3)*0.06 = 0.22 watts, so it should be rated for at least 0.5 W to avoid getting dangerously hot.

NiMH can handle some overcharge at low current, but for best lifespan you should match the charging time to the state of charge. This may be difficult to determine if it is partially discharged, in which case you should run it down until you know it is 'flat' (~1.1 V) before recharging for 12-14 hours.

Comment: Note that this method is usable for NiMH and lead-acid but certainly not for lithium cells, which must not be charged above their maximum voltage (4.2 or 4.3 at a push).

Comment: Can the cell be left charging like this with only a resistor indefinitely, or would that be dangerous?

Comment: @AndrewMorton not 'dangerous', but continuous charging at C/10 will _eventually_ damage the cell. [Here's](https://docs.rs-online.com/73f6/0900766b80deb2fa.pdf) an example that says C/10 is OK for 6 months,  C/33 for 12 months, and C/100 'forever'.